# vi insert text for specific line ranges

Tags: linux, vi

Seeking help in vi editor.

I want to insert in the begin of line. I wanted it to be insserted for specific line ranges. for eg, line number 1 to line number 20.

Any idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
:1,20s/^/#/
```

where 1 and 20 compose the line number range, and the # is the text to be inserted at the beginning of the line.

That's the simplest way to do it, but there's a whole thread on other things to try at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253380/how-do-i-insert-text-at-beginning-of-a-multi-line-selection-in-vi-vim

Comment: Thanks bobmagoo, I also just now got this link.  Thanks for your help.